# What's the proper way to slice cherub tomato for sandwiches that maximizes tomato flavor?

Tags: flavor, food-science, vegetables, tomatoes

I buy cherub tomatoes because I can use them all week in a variety of dishes and meals.

I'm looking for the best way to slice them for sandwiches to maximize the tomato flavor in a bite. I don't need to have tomato flavor in *every* bite, but when I do get it, I want to taste it.

I have two tomatoes of equal size. I slice one vertically in half, one horizontally in circles:

[image]

Put on bread, it looks like they take up about the same amount of surface.

It seems to me that the vertical, half slices produce more tomato flavor. Is there any cooking lore or guidance on how to slice things to get specific taste results?

Comment: i voted to reopen. As the op is asking whether a style of cut yields a better flavor release

Comment: Agreed, I'm looking for lore or guidance on how to get a specific taste result that can settle the debate. I'm happy to add a TL;DR and move my question further up in the post.

Comment: I think "how to slice _things_" may end up being too broad even if it is not considered too subjective. (Tomatoes have a a different composition than, say, a carrot or potato.)

Comment: @JC007B I have attempted to edit your question to hopefully be more objectively answerable. Feel free to change or undo if you are unhappy with the edit.

Comment: I would like to know how to slice them so they don't slide around so much. An issue I have when putting them on a hamburger.

Comment: The reason I closed is that the taste intensity is not all that dependent on objectively measurable criteria, and out of those which are measurable, slicing wouldn't contribute much. We could reopen and let people write answers which assume that all criteria besides the tomato slicing are being held equal, and discuss any effects which might then appear in the measurable factors - but the problem would be how to explain to people that, if such an answer finds slicing type A better than slicing type B, that this doesn't mean that people will (or should) find sandwiches with slicing type A...

Comment: ... tastier than sandwiches with slicing type B. Or, said another way, we can formulate the desired question (which slicing type produces the tastier sandwich) which has no objective answer, and therefore keep it closed, or formulate a different question, let people answer it, and have everybody who reads it make the wrong assumptions that they got answers to the first question (which they wanted to have answered). This is why I would prefer to leave the quesiton closed and won't use the mod hammer to reopen - but if it gets reopened by the community or by another mod, I won't close again.

Comment: To those who are not convinced by my prevoius comments, another explanation: If you have an individual X with a firm belief that slicing longitudinally is the tastiest, then this belief will likely have a much higher influence on the final taste for X than the difference in number of flavor molecules docking onto X's taste buds. Which is one of the main reasons why I would say the objectively answerable part (which will have probably restrict itself to approximating measures such as the amount of flavor molecules released) is worse than useless, making closure preferable.

Comment: @LSchoon - your edits are fine. I did more internet digging to see if I could find an objective answer to this. I found this article where chefs talk about how the more thinly you slice tomatoes, the more aroma released. Not a direct tie to taste but we know that smell and taste are closely tied. Seems to me, the short answer is circle slices produce more aroma, therefore will have a bigger impact on perceived taste. https://www.npr.org/sections/thesalt/2016/07/11/485235765/slice-dice-chop-or-julienne-does-the-cut-change-the-flavor

Comment: @rumtscho I understand your reasoning. I was hoping that a more-or-less objective question and answer could be constructed, because I know that for alliums, the way they are processed has a huge impact on the amount of certain compounds being produced. Who knows, maybe something similar can be said for tomatoes.. Perhaps all references to sandwiches should be removed to make this work, though.

Comment: According to The Food Lab, the direction in which the onions are sliced affect the flavor. https://twitter.com/thefoodlab/status/793495929781301249?s=21 I think it’s reasonable to ask a similar question for tomatoes.

Comment: With two examples of the objective answers that can be provided, can this question be reopened?